# How can i update the id when i use addEventListener?

Tags: javascript

i have two sections where i should click in some elements, each elements have differents id's when i click in this section: others.addEventListener('click', function (event) { the id is not updating, how can i update the id?

this example you can try clicking over the numbers

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    handleClick(e)
  });

  function dinamic(e) {
    const id = e.target.id

    let items = document.querySelectorAll("#test > div")
    let others = document.getElementById("test3")
    console.log("first part", id)
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      let item = items[i]
      item.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        let newBox = document.createElement("span")

        others.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
          console.log("second part", id)
        })

      });
    }
  }

  function handleClick(e) {
    dinamic(e)
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div class="test1" id="one">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="test2" id="two">
    2
  </div>
</div>

<div id="test3">
  3
</div>
```

note: when i used this part others.addEventListener('click', function (event) the up code is not executed

Comment: Changing the ID of something won't change what events are bound to it. Events are bound to the element, not the id. Your event handlers should be written to take that into account rather than adding/removing event handlers.

Comment: I think this is like adding a data-* attribute to element and you can handle it with event listener. You can handle a tooltip text from element attribute and render it in created box element on tooltip. So in this case, he does not want to change ID of element, only get the value of it. May be data-* attribute can be used instead of id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`id` is not updating because it is called in listener of section 1. So second part should be external part of it. In your code, second event listener will be created again for every click on section 1.

I created a snippet for you. I can help if i can not understand clearly. This is my solution:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const items = document.getElementsByClassName('test-item');
  const other = document.getElementById("test3")
  for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      dinamic(e, 'first part');
    });
  }
  other.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    dinamic(e, 'second part');
  })

  function dinamic(e, part) {
    const id = e.target.id;
    console.log(part, id)
    let newBox = document.createElement("span");
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div class="test-item" id="one">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="test-item" id="two">
    2
  </div>
</div>

<div id="test3">
  3
</div>
```